# OSX Chrome 69 does not respect window.open() height correctly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This was working fine until the latest chrome update (69).

```
window.open('https://www.google.com', 'test', 'width=500px, height=500px');
```

This opens a window with the correct width, but the height is wrong.

The `innerHeight` is 478px (supposed to be 500), and the `outerHeight` 528.

It makes no sense, the address bar and window bar take up 50px, so no idea why the `innerHeight` is 22px too short..

If you run the above in the console and then check the `innerHeight` of the window that has opened, it will be 22px short.

Any idea how to stop this from happening?

Comment: +1. Firefox does this just fine, I've used this function multiple times but have never checked to make sure dimensions were accurate. Unless you really really need these precise dimensions, you may have to just live with it for now. Curious to see what others will say.

Comment: Interestingly enough, Safari opens a window with `innerHeight` set to `478` and `outerHeight` set to `500`. Looks like someone screwed up calcs when the address bar region was tweaked in Chrome (webkit).